# Hide header and footer panel in Metabase

Tags: metabase

I have tried Metabase which is basically for charts and dashboards.
We integrated with an Java application using IFRAME so far everything fine.

But we want to remove header panel such as logo, icons.

It seems that not difficult but quite a job..[image]

Please anybody help us to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

## How can you embed without the Header

[image]

By using the built-in embedding you can remove the header, it'll give you a public URL like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/public/dashboard/928ff831-ee94-4200-9a71-1e87ce1643d3
```

Or you can follow the [documentation](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/administration-guide/13-embedding.html) to create a JWT embed if you need the URL to not be public.

## How can you embed without the Footer

For that you will need to pay for the unbranded embedding licence, you can find more info about that [here](https://store.metabase.com/product/embedding).